# Why do I have to use BACKTICKS when identifier is not a reserved word or with spaces?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mariadb, ddl

No ERROR on backticks.

```
DB [XXX]> create temporary table `123456e6` (`id` char (8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

ERROR when not using backticks.

```
DB [XXX]> create temporary table 123451e6 (`id` char (8));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '123451e6 (`id` char (8))' at line 1
```

My identifier 123451e6 is valid as per page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) and is not a reserved word or with spaces or contains any special character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered a subtle case of the "digit only" rule:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

The `e` character is used for scientific notation of numbers, and MySQL interprets 123451e6 as "123451 * 10<sup>6</sup>" or 123451000000. Any other letter but "e" would cause the string to adhere to the "not digits only" rule and could be used unquoted. E.g.:

```
MariaDB [db]> create temporary table 123451f6 (`id` char (8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid because something in the form of `12345e6` evaluates to a number, specifically 12345 * 10<sup>6</sup> in this example. Therefore you'll have to explicitly mark it as a string.

Comment: you mean an identifier and not a string.

Comment: @TheMagician It's interchangable in this situation. An identifier is a string, not a number, which is the initial problem.